# Alert message when select dropdown value is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have 4 dropdown options, where each dropdown depends on the other.

Dropdown B value depends on Dropdown A, so by default the value of all Dropdowns will be set to none.

If dropdown A's selected value is empty and dropdown B is selected, an alert message should be displayed.

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

So far I have this...

```
$( 'select#issueMonth" ).change(function() 
{ 
   if ( $(this).children(":selected").val() === "" ) 
   { 
      alert("empty"); 
   } 
});
```

Comment: Please, add some code in order to help you

Comment: My html code is <option value="">Month</option> and my jquery is $( 'select#issueMonth" ).change(function(){
          if ( $(this).children(":selected").val() === "" ) {
                alert("empty");
          }
    });

Comment: You have several typos in your js code. Make sure all double quotes are matched by double quotes and not single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

A full code snippet of the question would be preferred but perhaps try something like:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var str = "";
  $("select option:selected").each(function() {
    str += $(this).text() + " ";
  });
  if (str === "") {
    alert("empty");
  }
});
```

as adapted from the [jquery change api](https://api.jquery.com/change/) this code will add all the selections together into a temporary `str` variable which you can then check if empty. be sure to select the appropriate range of dropdowns through the selector.